# Can we develop C2C e-commerce site using magento?

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have search this topic but was not able to find a perfect solution. 
I wanted to know that if Magento can be useful to develop C2C e-commerce site. for example ebay.com, pond5.com, etc.
If yes, then how ? Are their any good article,book or tutorials available?

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Thanks,
Rakesh Gangani.

Comment: I think that its possible with  coding new extension, so that the customer can add products from the "my account" menu, and also must check the baying process to handle c2c transaction

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to build an extension that do these things:

1. add back-end permission control module for product and product category
2. auto create a product category and do related permission settings after creating a back-end user role
3. auto add related permission after users of the role creating a product

Set related permission to the role with Magento default function

Not good at explaining, hope this helps...

Comment: But what if i build an extension that will allow user to add product from "My Account" section with minimal field required. Obviously it will be a simple product. Bruce what do you comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found [an extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/c2c-multi-sellers-marketplace.html) which does exactly this. Here's what it says it can do:

> This extension converts your store to a multiple sellers platform. The
>   admin can set the commission for each seller. The seller is able to
>   login from the frontend to track their sales and payout from the My
>   Account page.